# Linux linear to physical address mapping

Tags: linux, x86, system

Linux initialises kernel code, kernel data, user code and user data to same 0x00000000(base) and 0xffffffff(limit). They span the same linear space. How does the paging unit differentiates between linear space of different segments. Does every segment have different page table.

Answer (score 1):

The [ELF standard](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) (Executable and Linkable Format) has been developed for that reason (organizing the different pieces of data into one binary). Among others, it has a header that specifies which segments are valid.

If your question is where, in terms of physical address, these segments are mapped, then the answer is that linker decides. There are many articles and e-books that describe the linker's functionality.

I reccommend [Advanced C and C++ Compiling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430266678) book to get the full picture.